# Windows 10 November Major update downloading whole windows again?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

I currently have `Windows 10.0.10240` i am trying to update to latest build which was released on 12th of november `Build 10586`

The update is now stopped due to insufficient space in C Drive and asking me to free up space for about more than 6 GB (almost 7 GB)
[image]

My problem is not with system space i can easily clean up mess.

The problem is why the heck Its downloading whole windows again? it is suppose to do that?

My problem is i have 3 windows devices i cannot download 7 GB of data in each devices. I know about delivering updates local network but on devices has different edition of Windows.

> I have checked there are no other pending updates its asking 7GB space for this single update

[image]

Comment: If you only want to download the data once, use the Media Creation Tool, or you can simply configure Windows Update to share updates within your own network.  The Media Creation tool will create a universal Professional/Home installation image.

Comment: I don't want to get the whole windows again i just want it download the latest files 

Is it supposed to download whole windows on major updates?

Comment: This isn't just a major update, the kernel is being updated also, Windows 10 will basically be upgraded to Windows 10 Version 1511.  This is basically an identical process Windows 8 users performed with the upgrade to Windows 8.1.  If you have Windows 10 Professional you can defer this update for a small period of time if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Version 1511 is not provided via a normal Update as MSU or CAB file. It is a new complete Windows which is provided via ESD file.

Comment: so if download it through windows update will it also upgrade my other system with different windows 10 edition

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you need to update several PCs, get the ISO from Microsoft: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench, mount the ISO on each PC, run setup.exe and select upgrade.

Comment: @AkashKumar - If you have that option enabled, it will use your local network traffic, to download this and all other updates I might add.  The update is large enough for precisely that purpose.

Comment: I have 3 devices.My 1st device has `windows 10 Pro` I am downloading window update from this device my second device has `windows 10 Single language` and 3rd has `Windows 10 Home`

So will i be able to upgrade my other devices to latest build with Windows 10 pro ESD File or I have to download separate ESD or ISO files to upgrade

Comment: in this case Windows Update downloads 3 matching ESDs.